# pyqt4 phonon videoplayer HLS stream play well at local machine(win7 64bit) but cannot play at other machine

Tags: python, pyqt4, phonon

I was made VideoPlayer(for HLS stream) with Python(v3.4.3 <32bit> Anaconda3)
and PyQT4(v4.8.6).
especially I use PyQT4.phonon's videoplayer.

And work hard...work..work...after..
Finally I finished applications. That play well in my local machine(win7 64bit).
so I build up to .exe file with cx_freeze(v4.3.4).
It play well too in my machine.

but problem occurs...
It cannot play start stream at other machine.
No error, execution is stable, GUI state good.
but just cannot start play video.

My python code includes some modules. (like below)

```
import sys
import base64
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
```

Player code are simple

```
...

self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(url))

self.player.play()

...
```

I copied all files and folders that after convert cx_freeze generate files all.
The other machine is Windows7 (64, 32), XP, bla..bla...
Other machine has not installed Python.

Why cannot play stream at the other machines... please help me.

Comment: Your sure all pyqt modules (that phonon relay on) are in installer/exe?

Comment: cx_freeze output folders & files below: imageformats (folder) phonon_backend (folder) -> inside "phonon_ds94.dll" _bz2.pyd library.zip phonon4.dll PyQt4.phonon.pyd PyQt4.QtCore.pyd PyQt4.QtGui.pyd python34.dll QtCore4.dll QtGui4.dll sip.pyd unicodedata.pyd vod.exe

Comment: Thx for comment Cox, My codes have 5 modules. -> import sys, import base64, from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon. cx_freeze output forders have phonon4.dll, PyQt4.phonon.pyd, PyQt4.QtCore.pyd, PyQt4.QtGui.pyd, python34.dll, qtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, sip.pyd, unicodedata.pyd.... There is no base64 relay file..but It don't necessary in my codes, Is this rights? –